# Junit5 set displayName programatically from extension

Tags: junit5

How can the display name of a test be defined programmatically, via an extension?

From the org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext I cannot find a way to access the display name. ClassExtensionContext and MethodExtensionContext are package private so I cannot unwrap like:

```java
((ClassExtensionContext) context).getTestDescriptor()

//or

((MethodExtensionContext) context).getTestDescriptor()
```

even if this was possible the displayName is private with no setter, so the only way was to use reflection which is not a good solution.

Comment: Does annotation `@DisplayNameGeneration`, which takes a `DisplayNameGenerator` class as a parameter, not fulfil your needs?

Comment: Don't want to use the annotation. The extension has the display name of the test. Using the `@DisplayNameGeneration` would require that besides the annotation from the extension I had to add extra one...also no idea how could I glue `@DisplayNameGeneration` in a way that could get the display name from the extension.

Comment: You cannot. The display name must be fixed before a test’s start event is being emitted. The extension, however, is invoked after the start event. So there’s no way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Do you know if this behavior will ever change?

Comment: Highly unlikely since this would require a complete revamp of JUnit‘s event mechanism. But you might want to create an issue on Github for it to ask the JUnit team.